# Remove big dependency that doesn't declare sideEffects from bundle

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have a **library** built with Webpack 4 that has a big bundle size due to a library that is always being included in the final bundle. Is there a way that doesn't involve dynamic imports to take just this dependency out to a separate chunk?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between bundling a library and bundling an application.

#### Application bundling

When you are bundling an application, you must bundle everything. Now, if your bundle is huge in size, so be it. If that is not acceptable, then you apply the optimizations. First, you can publish that library to some CDN and use the traditional `script` tag to include it and use `defer` or `async` attribute on that script. In your code, you should use Webpack [external](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) to tell Webpack to exclude this lib from the bundle and instead use the external copy.

#### Library bundling

If you are bundling a library, you must exclude all the dependencies i.e. the dependencies of your library. Your library's `package.json` should include list of dependencies which would then be installed by the application.

As per your question, you are bundling a library which means just this heavy dependency but also the other dependencies. Let the user of your library install the dependencies.

Further, you are using a dependency that is not using side effect but due to some edge-case issues like re-exporting all the modules into a barrel pattern or equivalent. So, Webpack would not be able do proper tree shaking with your bundle and ends up adding entire dependency code even if you are not using all the functionality.